# How do I check if a pixel is white?

Tags: java, opencv, pixel

I'm using OpenCV on Java (yes, I know) to read an image and a mask and merge them into one grayscale image in which pixels are floats in range of [0,1], and hole pixels are -1 (defined by white part of mask).

I'm going through the mask pixel by pixel to find the white ones.

Here's my code:

```
import static java.awt.Color.white;

public static Mat merge(Mat orig, Mat mask) {
        Mat img = new Mat(orig.rows(), orig.cols(), CV_32F); // Create Mat of float values
        float[] holePixel = {-1};
        for (int i = 0; i < orig.rows(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < orig.cols(); j++) {
                if (mask.get(i, j).equals(white)) {// If pixel is part of hole in mask
                    img.put(i, j, holePixel);
                    System.out.println("FOUND A WHITE"); // <--------- this print
                } else {
                    double[] pixel = orig.get(i, j);
                    float grayVal = (float) ((pixel[0] + pixel[1] + pixel[2]) / 3) / 255; // Create grayscale value
                    float[] grayPix = {grayVal};
                    img.put(i, j, grayPix);
                }
            }
        }
        return img;
    }
```

I put that print to know wether it found white pixels or didn't. It didn't. My mask has white pixels.
Seems my way of comparison doesn't work, what should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint on the line with the `if`, and step through with the debugger.  Have a look and see what kinds of values are coming out of `mask.get(i,j)`.  This may give you a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: `java.awt.Color.white` is a `Color`, not a `double[]` like `mask.get(i, j)` is returning.  They will never be equal. I don't know enough about OpenCV to know how to reconcile the data, but you need to get them into the same format before comparing them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys. I ended up checking manually what's in a white pixel and realised I have to compare value by value, so I made a small method to tell me if a pixel is white. If this helps anybody in the future, I compared each value from double[] to 255.0 (all must be 255.0 for a pixel to be white)